# получить подкомментарии - многомерность

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, проектирование

есть 2 таблицы: в одной комментарии, в другой подкомментарии... связь по полю. Делаю следующий запрос, для получения многомерного массива с комментариями и подкомментариями:

```
SELECT
 comments.comment_text,
 pcomments.pcomment_text 
FROM comments 
LEFT JOIN 
 pcomments using(сid)
```

но в ответ получаю дубликаты типа:

```
Array
(
    [comment_text] =>  HELLO! ITEM 1
    [pcomment_text] => подкомментарий 1
)
Array
(
    [comment_text] => HELLO! ITEM 1
    [pcomment_text] => подкомментарий 2
)
```

как вы видите все "разложено" отдельно - нельзя ли сделать так при запросе:

```
Array
(
    [comment_text] =>  HELLO! ITEM 1
    [pcomment_text] => array(
          [0] => подкомментарий 1,
          [1] => подкомментарий 2
    )
)
```

и так для каждого комментария

Comment: Зачем вам отдельная таблица подкомментариев?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы хотите сделать можно, но уже средствами php. Ещё можно для каждого комментария отдельным запросом запрашивать подкомментарии, но я так делать не советую.

Как правильно заметил @Etki, гораздо правильнее убрать таблицу подкомментарии, а в таблице комментарии добавить поле `parent_comment_id`.

Comment: теперь не получается составить sql запрос для получения родителей и их детей.. приведите пример, если не трудно

Answer (score 1):

Средствами PHP:

```
$double = array(
    Array
    (
        "comment_text" =>  "HELLO! ITEM 1",
        "pcomment_text" => "подкомментарий 1"
    ),
    Array
    (
        "comment_text" => "HELLO! ITEM 1",
        "pcomment_text" => "подкомментарий 2"
    )
);

var_dump($double);

$result = $double[0];
$keys = array_keys($result);
$pcomm = end($keys);
$comm = prev($keys);
$result[$pcomm]=array($result[$pcomm]);
array_walk($double, function($item) use(&$result, $comm, $pcomm){
    if(($item[$comm] == $result[$comm]) && (!in_array($item[$pcomm],$result[$pcomm]))){
        array_push($result[$pcomm], $item[$pcomm]);

    }
});

var_dump($result);
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'comment_text' => string 'HELLO! ITEM 1' (length=13)
      'pcomment_text' => string 'подкомментарий 1' (length=30)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'comment_text' => string 'HELLO! ITEM 1' (length=13)
      'pcomment_text' => string 'подкомментарий 2' (length=30)

array (size=2)
  'comment_text' => string 'HELLO! ITEM 1' (length=13)
  'pcomment_text' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'подкомментарий 1' (length=30)
      1 => string 'подкомментарий 2' (length=30)
```